# Bootstrap4 dropdown link issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

My dropdown is working perfectly but "Documents" link is not routing to the link.

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="./docs/index.html" data-target="./docs/index.html" target="_blank" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Documents</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Admin</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Merchant</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Is location for the page correct?

Comment: Yes location is correct, even I checked for # or https://www.google.com its still not working

Comment: Ok, try this href="docs/index.html"

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49548895/bootstrap-4-dropdown-menu-href-link-not-going-to-href-location)

Comment: I tried this but it's still not working for any link

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" >Documents</a>
    <span class="dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    </span>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Admin</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Merchant</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

change `href` url as per your requirements.

I hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks it just helped me by doing little adjustment